Lack of information in GAMESS output for example "Building a linked model for a HEME group with MCPB.py" in AMBER
I am currently trying to optimize the geometry of a complex using GAMESS at the B3LYP level. My complex is the HEMO group (Fe3+ atom at the center of a porphyrin ring), with a charge of -2 and multiplicity of 6. I am not sure if this is correct since the results do not show a successful completion result nor an abnormal exit message. Also in the example at https://ambermd.org/tutorials/advanced/tutorial20/mcpbpy_heme.php in the quantum mechanics calculation with GAMESS or Gaussian, they mention the value of the charge and multiplicity the same as I mentioned above.
